# Can't bind child collection in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have a pretty simple setup that I cannot get to work in silverlight.  I have an order with a collection of OrderPayments.  These objects are part of a Entity Framework model and are exposed through WCF RIA Services.  I can bind perfectly fine to any basic property on the Order class, but I wanted to bind to a listbox to show the OrderPayments.  Here's the XAML for the ListBox.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data.OrderPayments, ElementName=orderDataSource}"></ListBox>
```

Nothing ever appears in the listbox and there is at least one OrderPayment for the order displayed.  orderDataSource is a DomainDataSource that contains the Order.  The odd thing about this is that I don't receive any binding errors and when I bind to a TextBlock using the following code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.OrderPayments, ElementName=orderDataSource}" />
```

The text 'OrderPayment' is outputted to the screen.  Is there something different I have to do to get Silverlight to actually pick up the reference to the object?

Entire XAML below:

```
<riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="True" Name="orderDataSource" QueryName="GetOrder">
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
            <riaControls:Parameter ParameterName="orderid" Value="1" />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <ds:CEWCPSDomainContext />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="12">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Width="100" Height="50" Content="Save &amp; Return" Margin="0,0,12,12" />
            <Button Width="100" Height="50" Content="Orders" Margin="0,0,12,12" />
            <Button Width="100" Height="50" Content="Emails" Margin="0,0,12,12" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <dataForm:DataForm x:Name="dataForm1" Header="Order Contact Information" 
                       AutoGenerateFields="False" AutoEdit="False" AutoCommit="False" 
                      CurrentItem="{Binding Data, ElementName=orderDataSource}">
                <dataForm:DataForm.EditTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <dataForm:DataField Label="First Name">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True }" />
                        </dataForm:DataField>
                        <dataForm:DataField Label="Last Name">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True }"/>
                        </dataForm:DataField>
                        <dataForm:DataField Label="Organization">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Organization, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True }"/>
                        </dataForm:DataField>
                        <dataForm:DataField Label="Phone">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Phone, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True }"/>
                        </dataForm:DataField>
                        <dataForm:DataField Label="Fax">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Fax, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True }"/>
                        </dataForm:DataField>
                        <dataForm:DataField Label="Email">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True }"/>
                        </dataForm:DataField>
                        <dataForm:DataField Label="Address 1">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Address1, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True }"/>
                        </dataForm:DataField>
                        <dataForm:DataField Label="Address 2">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Address2, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True }"/>
                        </dataForm:DataField>
                        <dataForm:DataField Label="City">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding City, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True }"/>
                        </dataForm:DataField>
                        <dataForm:DataField Label="State">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding State, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True }"/>
                        </dataForm:DataField>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto">
                            <dataForm:DataField Label="Zip code">
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Zip, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True }"/>
                            </dataForm:DataField>
                            <dataForm:DataField>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Zip4, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True }"/>
                            </dataForm:DataField>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <dataForm:DataField Label="Country">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Country, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True }"/>
                        </dataForm:DataField>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </dataForm:DataForm.EditTemplate>
            </dataForm:DataForm>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Text="Order Total / Payments" />
                <TextBlock >
                    <Run Text="Order Total:" />
                    <Run Text="{Binding Data.OrderTotal, ElementName=orderDataSource}" />
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="Payments" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.OrderPaymentItems, ElementName=orderDataSource}" />
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data.OrderPayments, ElementName=orderDataSource}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Amount}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>

            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: What is triggering the load of your DomainDataSource? You are only binding to the collection on the DomainDataSource *that will be filled at some point*. If this is being done in code-behind please provide some hints :)

Comment: It is declarative in the XAML.  The order is loaded fine and all other fields are displayed on the form.  Just this child collection doesn't seem to really contain items, it is just seems to have a name of the object it holds.

Comment: In that case can you provide more XAML? The problem with bindings are that they display nothing if there is no matching binding element, so could be as simple as a typo if your list is empty.

Comment: I built a sample app with the AdventureWorks database, to test the problem, and found exactly the same thing. Any nested object queries evaluate to an empty enumeration. I was also under the impression that they would evaluate correctly. I will get back to you if I find out more about this. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF RIA Services does not include child entities by default.  I needed to put [Include()] on the OrderPayments property of the Order object.  Works like a charm now.

Comment: That's definitely worth a +1. Glad you found it :)

Comment: I have the same issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764924/chart-control-not-showing-series even though I have "included" my child entities as [Include]
[Association("Server_RamInfos", "Name", "ServerName")]
public List<RamInfoDTO> RamInfo { get; set; }
but {Binding RamInfo.Name} or .Value comes as Null...any thoughts??